# C++ How to check if all array elements are equal / different? Also how to display all different elements which are used at least 1 time?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

How to check if all array elements are equal?
Example:
1 2 3
exit: NO
Example 2:
2 2 2 2
exit: YES
I wrote this, but it always displays "NO" :

```
# include < iostream >    
using namespace std;    
int main(){    
int n , a[ n ] , i;    
cin>>n;    
cout<< endl;    
for(i=0 ; i<=n-1 ; i++)    
{    
     cin>>a[ i ];    
}  
if (a[ i ]! = a[ i + 1 ]) {cout<<"NO";}    
else {cout<<"YES";}    
return 0;    
}
```

For the second program:
Example:
1 2 2 5 7 2 9 1 5 8
exit:  1 2 5 7 8

I have to sort the program with Selection Sort, Bubble Sort or Insertion
THANK YOU :)

Comment: That code won't compile.

Comment: `if (std::find_if(a, a+n, [a](int x) { return x != a[0]; }) == a+n) { /* all elements equal */ }`

Comment: `std::set<int> unique_values(a, a+n);` Printing out the contents of the set is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: In the 4rd line `n` is still unknown, as you ask for its value in line 5, so using `a[n]` in line 4 is not going to work.

Comment: Furthermore, it is probably a better idea to ask your 2 questions in separate questions. So people will/can focus better on the separate questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make an array with range `n` when `n` isn't intialized.

```
int n , a[ n ] , i;    
cin>>n;
```

Further, you currently use `i` with the value `n` in the if-statement. That will not work. You are accessing outside the values just entered in the array and - worse - outside array boundaries.

You need a loop for the check:

```
int main(){    
    int n , i;    
    cin>>n;    
    int a[n];    // n must be initialized first
    cout<< endl;  

    for(i=0 ; i<=n-1 ; i++)    // Read in array values
    {    
        cin>>a[ i ];    
    }

    for(i=0 ; i<=n-2 ; i++)   // Check array value in a loop. Notice: i <=n-2
    {      
        if (a[i] != a[i+1]) 
        {
            cout << "NO";
            return 0;
        }
    }    

    cout << "YES";    
    return 0;
}
```

However, in C++ it is much easier to use the standard containers instead of old C-style arrays. Use `vector`and `set` like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
using namespace std; 

int main(){    
    int n , i;    
    vector<int> a;   // Use vector instead array to hold the data 
    set<int> unique; // Use set for finding unique values as a set
                     // can only hold a specific value one time

    cin >> n;    
    for(i=0 ; i<n ; i++)    
    {   
        int tmp;
        cin >> tmp;  
        a.push_back(tmp);    // Put value into vector
        unique.insert(tmp);  // Put value into set
    }  

    if (unique.size() == 1)
    {
        cout << "YES" << endl;    
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "NO" << endl;    
    }

    cout << "Unique value:" << endl;
    for (auto v : unique)
    {
        cout << v << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Finally notice that the `vector` isn't used for solving your problem. The `set`is sufficient for that. I used the `vector` so that input data was still saved somewhere in case you needed to do more with it - if not, you can delete the `vector`part.

For your second program:

Google: "wiki bubble sort" and you'll find  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comes with pseudo code and all.